# Printing with Quotes

Tags: python, string, input, integer, boolean

How come when I use the program below i keep getting "y" in quotes opposed to the value defined by y, which would be the string entered by the user

```
def main():
    x = (input("Give me a boolean: ").lower() == 'true')     
    y = str(input("Give me a string: "))
    z = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    if x == True:
        print (y)
        print ("\"",y,"\"",sep="")
    else:
        print (z*2)



main()
```

Comment: What? I don't understand the question... Can you explain? By the way, your `or true` is wrong and useless.

Comment: Okay if the user enters "true" or "True" for "give me a boolean," I want it to print the string(y) twice, once with quotes and once without it

Comment: just a hint .. the string `"False"` is `True`.  Maybe `x` should be `input("boolean: ").lower() == "true"`

Comment: @adsmith unless `true` is defined.  And if `true` is `True` then the `if` condition will always be met, and if `true` is `False` then the `or` part of the condition doesn't do anything.

Comment: I was going to do an {if} [else] statement I just havent made it that far in the code, I was just trying to get the quote issue figured out before i wrote the else statement

Comment: @user3331010 none of the suggestions so far have precluded any further `if/elif/else` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's talk about booleans, because this is actually the problem here.

```
x = bool(input("Give me a boolean: "))
# x is ALWAYS True unless the user enters an empty string
```

The problem here is that all non-empty strings are boolean `True`. `"Hello"` is `True`, `"TRUE"` is `True`, and `"False"` is `True`. The only string that evaluates to `False` is `""`. So when you prompt for input here, then test it later, you're always going to pass that test unless the user just bypasses the test. Let's move on...

```
y = str(input("Give me a string: ")) # good here, though no need to call str()
z = int(input("Give me a number: ")) # uh oh...
```

If I enter `ajkldfj` for z, it will throw a `ValueError`. The usual way to handle this is `try/except`, e.g.:

```
z = input("Give me a number: ")
try:
    int(z)
except ValueError as e:
    # handle it
```

Next up...

```
if x == True or true:
```

This is the same issue that TONS of people have. `if foo == 1 or 2` doesn't mean what you think it does, it actually means `if (foo == 1 is True) or (2 is True)`. To do what you're trying to do, you should do `if x == "True" or x == "true"`, but better is `if x.lower() == "true"` and better still is `if x.casefold() == 'true'` but BEST YET is just `if x`. Remember, you're already turning it into a `bool` when you prompt for it. You can change that of course by dropping the `bool()` call, then testing for it here, in which case I recommend `if x.lower() == 'true'` or `if x.casefold() == 'true'`. The other code you'll see quite often is `if x in ('true','True')`, but since we can just lowercase to remove all ambiguity: DO IT!

Now to your print statements:

```
    print (y)     # prints the value in y
    print ('"y"') # prints "y"
```

If this isn't what you want to do, you can use string formatting or really any of a bazillion other things to format it correctly. Let me know what you want to do and we can talk further!

Comment: Okay I just updated my program and put it up top, the only issue im having now is if I print "true" or "false" when i do this it says both true and false are undefined

Comment: `true` and `false` are both undefined. `True` is the boolean value True, and `False` is the boolean value false. Capitalization is important. In addition, `"true"` and `"false"` are strings, but you need to wrap them in quotation marks to indicate that. Somewhat confusingly (and as I mentioned in the first paragraph), all strings that aren't empty (e.g. `""` is a string with length zero) evaluate to `True`, so `"false"` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @user3331010 also, and IMPORTANTLY, absolutely under no circumstances that will ever come up in the next two to three years of you learning programming is `eval` the correct way to do ANYTHING. Remove that from your code *tout suite*!

Comment: Instead, if you want `x` to be the boolean `True` if and only if the user enters `"True","true","TRUE", etc...`, do `x = input("Give me a boolean: ").lower() == 'true'`. The `==` operator returns `True` or `False`, and doing it right there will prompt the user for input, translate it to lowercase, and check it against the string `"true"`.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, you've helped alot, but just out of curiosity why is [eval] so bad, my cs teacher uses it alot in examples for converting blooeans and number inputs

Comment: It's not that `eval` is bad, it's that `eval(input())` is bad. If you do that with an untrusted user (e.g. ANY user but yourself), and they enter, for instance, `import os; for file in os.listdir(r"C:\windows\system32"): os.remove(file)`, Python will execute that code, which deletes everything in your system32 folder. It's not hard to see why that would be a Bad Thing :)

Comment: @user3331010 essentially, `eval` treats anything you pass to it as valid Python code. That can be a Good Thing if you know exactly what you're doing and why, but it means that anyone who can WRITE valid Python code can completely take over your application if you let them write to `eval`. In no circumstance is it EVER good code to do `eval(input())`. Your CS instructor can use it to do `eval("True")` which will run `"True"` assuming it's code (which it is, the boolean `True`), and `eval("1")` to get the integer `1`, but it's not a good way to do either of those things...............

Answer (score 0):

you must use below line for print only y

```
print(y)
```

and below for y with Parentheses

```
print( "(" + y + ")")
```

`Warning:`**in your Code if X==False then python give you below error**

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` alongside print.

```
print("({0})".format(y))
```

Where `0` references the first argument passed to format, `1` the second, and so on.  Also, you're doing `x == True or true`, the `or true` is wrong and should be removed.  Also `bool("True") == bool("False") == True`, since strings (of length > 0) are `True` in Python, you probably want something like

```
x = str(input("True/False? "))
y = str(input("Input string: "))
z = int(input("Number: "))
if x.lower() == "true":
    print("({0})".format(y))
```

**Edit**: Sample session

```
>>> def main():
    x = str(input("True/False? "))
    y = str(input("Input string: "))
    z = int(input("Number: "))
    if x.lower() == "true":
        print("({0})".format(y))

>>> main()
True/False? false
Input string: dog
Number: 2

>>> main()
True/False? true
Input string: dog
Number: 2
(dog)
```

Comment: CAn I not use an [if] [elise] statement, I wasnt finished with the code so I didnt make it that far, I was trying to fix the quote issue before I worked on the Else: statement

Comment: What do you mean not use an if-else statement?

Comment: @hkpeprah if you're only formatting one word, it's usually not worth it to make the expensive `str.format` call. Just `print("(" + str(y) + ")")`

Comment: @adsmith He wants to format the string in brackets, so `str(y)` isn't going to cut it.  Either `"(" + y + ")"`, `"(%s)"%y` or `"({0})".format(y)`.  It doesn't seem like OP was going for performance, but of course they're there.